# Find the best team using some algorithm

Tags: algorithm, math, combinations

For a 7's side soccer, I have got 21 players with their 'positions and ratings'. I would like to find best team via programming. Is there any algorithm or mathematical formula I can use to find the 'best' team based on player's rating.
Then find the 'second' order best team  and so on.  I am happy with 3-3-1 format ( 3 Forwards, 3 Defense and 1 GK )

I have got 21 Players here

```
Player  Position   Rating

Vin      F          2.75
Max      D          3.5
Jack     F          4.25
Doen     D          3.75
Ter      F          2.85
Min      GK         3.55
Mor      F          4.25
TOY      D          3.85
Jut      D          2.25
Per      F          4.75
Tod      F          4.58    
GER      D          4.65
YAH      D          4.36
KET      F          3.95
FEL      D          2.82
MET      GK         3.56
Jee      F          2.99
LO       D          3.36
UT       F          3.88
GGT      D          4.15
UUT      GK         4.25
```

Comment: How would you do it with a pen and paper? It's pretty simple barely scrapes in as an algorithm...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Comment: You haven't explained what "best" means in quantitative terms, nor have you made any discernible attempt to attack the problem yourself.

Comment: One of the things that you're looking for is called an "objective function," which is a mathematical formula that you try to maximize to describe the "best" team. For example, for the Forwards - are three Forwards each with a rating of 4.0 (for a total of 12.0) absolutely equivalent to two Forwards with a 2.0 and one Forward with an 8.0 (also for a total of 12.0)? Or is that *better* then three equals because there's one "superstar?" Or is that *worse* because there are two guys who aren't very good? Once you figure that out, maximizing it for 3 forwards, 3 Defense, and 1 GK should be easy.

Comment: @BobGilmore Appreciate your inputs, will try that way. There will be more players added to this list later. Also there will be a real auction and bidding happening on these
players too. Since time is less during auction, I was looking for an option to mitigate it, rather than writing on a paper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know what programming language you are going to use, or how you are to handle data, but below is my quick solution.

BTW, I chose Javascript, cause it is easy to make a demo.

```js
function getPos(pos) {
    return function(player) {
        return player['Position'] == pos;
    }
}
function selectSquad(el, t) {
    let teams = [],
        arr = t.slice(),
        i=0;
    while(arr.length >= 7) {
        let remains = [],
            selectedSquad = []; 
        Object.keys(el).forEach( function(k, v) {
            let playersInPositions = arr.filter(getPos(k)),
                selected = playersInPositions.sort(function compare(a, b){
                    let y = a.Rating, z = b.Rating;
                    return z - y;
                }).splice(0,el[k]);

            remains.push(playersInPositions);
            selectedSquad.push(selected);
        });
        arr = [].concat.apply([], remains);
        teams[i] = selectedSquad.slice();
        i++;
    }
    return teams;
}

let team = [
  {"Player":"Vin","Position":"F","Rating":2.75},
  {"Player":"Max","Position":"D","Rating":3.5},
  {"Player":"Jack","Position":"F","Rating":4.25},
  {"Player":"Doen","Position":"D","Rating":3.75},
  {"Player":"Ter","Position":"F","Rating":2.85},
  {"Player":"Min","Position":"GK","Rating":3.55},
  {"Player":"Mor","Position":"F","Rating":4.25},
  {"Player":"TOY","Position":"D","Rating":3.85},
  {"Player":"Jut","Position":"D","Rating":2.25},
  {"Player":"Per","Position":"F","Rating":4.75},
  {"Player":"Tod","Position":"F","Rating":4.58},
  {"Player":"GER","Position":"D","Rating":4.65},
  {"Player":"YAH","Position":"D","Rating":4.36},
  {"Player":"KET","Position":"F","Rating":3.95},
  {"Player":"FEL","Position":"D","Rating":2.82},
  {"Player":"MET","Position":"GK","Rating":3.56},
  {"Player":"Jee","Position":"F","Rating":2.99},
  {"Player":"LO","Position":"D","Rating":3.36},
  {"Player":"UT","Position":"F","Rating":3.88},
  {"Player":"GGT","Position":"D","Rating":4.15},
  {"Player":"UUT","Position":"GK","Rating":4.25}
]

let formation = {
    "GK": 1,
    "D" : 3,
    "F" : 3
}

// selectSquad(formation, team);

console.log(selectSquad(formation, team));
```

> **PS:** You can change the formation to anything you would like, just change the lines below and you're good to go.

```
let formation = {
    "GK": 1,
    "D" : 3,
    "F" : 3
}
```

> **EDİT:** If you change the formation, let's say (1,4,2) The system will still continue, but as there are not enough defenders left, the last team is going to have only one defender. That's why you need to add some sort of a validation to make the system work correctly.